# How to allow only my domain and subdomain to access files using .htacess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, block

i have one site and subdomain for blog, and other for downloads, example: (i using wordpress)

```
    mysite.com
    blog.mysite.com
    download.mysite.com
```

I need block direct access for all on **download.mysite.com** for any URL, and allow access only if file is accessed via my site or blog, example:

I put this url on my site **mysite.com**

```
    download.mysite.com/mysoftware.exe (this file is accessed normally)
```

i put this url on other site that no my site **anysite.com**

```
    download.mysite.com/mysoftware.exe (this file is blocked!)
```

if the URL is access via **blog.mysite.com** or **mysite.com** the file is access normally, but if the file is access direct with URL or with other domain that no my, example no-mysite.com, the file is blocked...

I found this code for **.htacess**

```
    Order Allow, Deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from mysite.com
    Allow from www.mysite.com
    Allow from blog.mysite.com
    Allow from www.blog.mysite.com
```

but dont work for me, my domain also are blocked... I need allow any sub urls on my site, example **mysite.com/thelink/on/this/page**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to be using mod_access to allow specific sites access, as that filters by the *HOST/IP* of the person making the request, not where the request is being referred from. I think you want to be checking the referer, as that's how you know where something is linked from.

The thing to keep in mind is that there is no guarantee that you're actually keeping people fro leeching your stuff, as the referer is trivial to forge. But you can add some rewrite rules to handle this kind of thing.

Make sure mod_rewrite is loaded in your webserver and add these rules *before* any rules that's already in your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://blog\.mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://download\.mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Works only for images (png, bmp, jpg, gif) and txt, for archive dont work (rar, zip, exe)... any suggestion?

Comment: @rflfn there is no restriction on any file type or any request, **every request** made to the host `download.mysite.com` will be denied if it doesn't come from of the the 3 hostnames in the referer condition

Comment: Please access this link: [link](http://dl.rflfn.com/public/files/downloads/soft/image.png), i upload this files, change extension image.png to this (image.bmp, image.gif, image.jpg) this are restrict, works correct! but this not (image.rar, image.zip)... im using your code exactly with your post.

Comment: View here, this works perfectly: [link](http://dl.rflfn.com/public/files/downloads/soft/image.png), but this dont block [link](http://dl.rflfn.com/public/files/downloads/soft/image.rar), im using your code... I need block all without my site referer, if that is not possible using htacess, would have any other way to do this? or somehow safer? host files allow to be downloaded only when purchased, can not run the risk of passing the link to someone else...

Comment: @rflfn when I click on that rar link, it is blocked. Are you sure you don't have files cached by your browser?

Comment: Yes... sorry... are exactly this, I thought it was not working, and was looking for another solution, i found this site [link](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/), it generates the file **.htacess** with the restrictions you need ... My problem is solved, thanks for your help! by the way, your solution works perfectly!

Comment: I have other question, is possible show message for block users? or redirect to URL?